# SharePoint Foundation SSA certificate validation error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, validation, sharepoint-search, certificate, searchserviceapplication

I am experiencing some issues on my SPF Server. 
Everytime I search, it takes about 15 seconds or more. I tracked this down to a certificate error.

> A certificate validation operation took 14581,1762 milliseconds and
>   has exceeded the execution time threshold.  If this continues to
>   occur, it may represent a configuration issue.

My Server is not connected to the Internet unfortunately.
Is there any workaround to this?

Thank you in advance, Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable certificate revocation list (CRL check) on your SharePoint Servers.

[Here](https://kb4sp.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/certificate-revocation-list-disable-check/) is shown how you can achieve this.